# Using PyPDF Rect as area input to Tabula

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, tabula

I'm trying to use the coordinates of the Rect object that PyPDF gives me as an area input to Tabula, but it seems like the coordinates are not the same, and I can't find information about the measure units those libraries use.

For example

I can find the same text rectangle in `PyPDF` and `Tabula` using the following coordinates:

```
PyPDF: Upper left = x: 208, y: 574; Lower right = x: 494, y: 585

Tabula: Upper left = x: 200, y: 240; Lower right = x: 510, y: 270
```

But I can't find a way to convert from `PyPDF` rectangle to `Tabula` area. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Seems like they use the same measure unit, just needed to invert the y axis using the page height.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional code. Please [edit] to add the code that helped you to solve the problem.